# How to make an php project accessibile within svn repo?

Tags: php, svn

Hey I've a svn repository with some php files and I want to run it over the browser. Just like a normal page. But if I go to the repo url (http://server-URL/svn) enter my username/pass, navigate to my php project and selecting the index.php it just shows me the content of the index.php but not the real rendered page.
How can I run my project?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you're using something like mod-svn in Apache to deal with your SVN repository.

If you want to run the PHP then you'll need to set up another virtualroot on Apache that isn't using mod-svn and give it a root directory which matches the location of the PHP files.

Basically, you can't manage the repository and parse the files from the same URL.

Comment: ok can you give me an advice how to fix the webserver setup that it works?

Comment: Indeed, have a checkout somewhere, and if you really want the latest SVN-revision there, just add a post-commit hook to the repo which updates the checkout.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I'd expect *viewing* the project contents through the svn interface. What you want is to actually upload the php project to a php-enabled website/host.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is just a repository. You would want to "check out" the code to your local machine and have a PHP Web Server setup. 
Of course, you could host it in a real website also.